# Error when downloading pyomo on Spyder IDE

Tags: conda, pyomo

Instructions says i should type "conda install –c conda-forge pyomo" to console but when i did that, i got an error

```
In [1]: conda install –c conda-forge pyomo
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[1], line 1
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('conda', 'install –c conda-forge pyomo')

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2456 in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:30 in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:128 in conda
    conda = _get_conda_like_executable("conda")

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:53 in _get_conda_like_executable
    match = re.search(

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\__init__.py:176 in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\__init__.py:294 in _compile
    p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_compiler.py:743 in compile
    p = _parser.parse(p, flags)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:982 in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:457 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:865 in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:457 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:541 in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)

  File ~\anaconda3\Lib\re\_parser.py:395 in _escape
    raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))

error: incomplete escape \U
```

i already tried to update ipython, conda etc, still doesn't work

I basically have no coding experience, im going to use this for my operational research class.

Comment: `conda` commands are entered on your system console (e.g. Windows command prompt), not the Python console.

Comment: You need to run this `conda install –c conda-forge pyomo` in an Anaconda terminal. Search for **Anaconda Prompt** in your windows search bar.